# How to display an array of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a some code in my controller:

```
def index
 @tasks = Task.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12 )    
 @tasks_row = task_to_rows(@tasks)

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @tasks }
 end
end
```

task_to_rows:

```
def task_to_rows(tasks)
  item_at_row = 0
  task_row = Array.new
  for i in (0..tasks.length)
    item_at_row += 1
    if item_at_row == 1
      temp_arr = Array.new
      temp_arr << tasks[i]
      task_row << temp_arr
    elsif item_at_row <= 3
      temp_arr << tasks[i]
      task_row << temp_arr
    end
    item_at_row = 0 if item_at_row == 3
  end

  return task_row
end
```

Method is needed to that each element of the array was an array of three elements. And to be able to show information like this: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s8/sh/5dee1bbd-af05-4432-9e24-586de98f4452/a8229d8d3fd0bb222a76a927a70ee507

In view I have:

```
<% @tasks_row.each do |task3| %>
  <h3>Row</h3>
  <% task3.each do |task| %>
    <%= task.name %>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

But Rails display a error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

If debug, then all works fine and shows.

**UPDATE:**
In the final version I just need to display the data in this format:

```
<div class="row>
  <div class="span3">Some data</div>
  <div class="span3">Some data</div>
  <div class="span3">Some data</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3">Some data</div>
  <div class="span3">Some data</div>
  <div class="span3">Some data</div>
</div>
.........
```

Comment: hm, what does `<% @tasks_row.each do |task3| %>
  <%= task3 %>
<% end -%>` return  or what does the final array structure look like??

Comment: <% @tasks_row.each do |task3| %>
    <h3>Row</h3>
    <%= task3 %>  
    <h3>end Row</h3>
   <% end -%>
it return https://www.evernote.com/shard/s8/sh/7a79cae1-0604-4047-9019-d4ea35d527c3/fad7a23231aa4623edcbf7c8331164b4

Comment: are you getting data in @tasks when you are not in debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand `task_to_rows` correctly, you want the array grouped by 3 right? In that case, I suggest you use `each_slice(3)` instead. The method you added is error prone and may result to some nil elements which causes the error.  Remember that `tasks[i]` can become `nil` if `i` is greater than or equal to the length of your array.  This is most probably where the error comes in since you are using `tasks.length`. So you have 2 choices.

**Choice 1**

Change

```
for i in (0..tasks.length)
```

to

```
for i in (0..(tasks.length - 1))
```

**Choice 2**

Use `each_slice(3)`

```
@tasks_row = @tasks.each_slice(3)
```